# pg-promise quick way to delete set of tuples

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql, sql-delete, pg-promise

Is there a better way to write the following:

```
DELETE FROM
    table
WHERE
    _id = $<id>
    AND (
        item_id = $<item_id>
        AND map_id = $<map_id>
        OR
        item_id = $<another_id>
        AND map_id = $<another_map_id>
        ...
    )
```

The dataset format I have is:

```
[
    {
        item_id: "some_id",
        map_id: "other_id"
    }
    ...
]
```

What would be a good way to write this in `pg-promise`, or even just plain postgreSQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sql
DELETE FROM table
WHERE
    _id = $<id>
    AND (item_id, map_id) IN ($<values:raw>)
```

If you have the following as your input data:

```js
const input = [
    {
        item_id: 'some_id',
        map_id: 'other_id'
    }
    ...
];
```

then you can generate `values` with [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) as follows (see [helpers.values](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.html#.values)):

```js
const values = pgp.helpers.values(input, ['item_id', 'map_id']);
```

or you can pass columns as a full [ColumnSet](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.ColumnSet.html), if more details are needed, like type casting, etc.

Comment: since I also have a `$<id>` I'm guessing i would make the query as: `pgp.result(sql_query, { id: 'some id', values }` right?

Comment: @A.L One uses method [result](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#result) only when you need something back from the result object, like number of deleted rows, for example, then you can do: `db.result(sql, {id, values}, r => r.rowCount)`, Otherwise, you can just use method [none](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#none).

Comment: yeah I'm using `rowCount` to ensure that the right number of rows are deleted, otherwise I will send some error/warning message. I'm also using `await` so I don't use functions

Comment: a bit off the topic/question, but what would be function to use if you had an array of arrays (2d array).

Comment: And then how would you define the columns? I would need to see such array first, and how you are trying to use it. Anyway, that is off-topic, so let's not digress here, this is not what comment section is for.

Comment: Ah yep, I see the issue now, as I would still need the identifying columns. It was more of a thought than "I actually have a problem". My solution would be to map those arrays to an object and do the same `values` function. Keeping this here as a note to myself.

Comment: @A.L No, you do not need to re-map anything. You can just use `ColumnSet`, with each column virtualized, with redirected source. For example, if you have 2 elements in each such array, your columns in `ColumnSet` can be defined as: `{ name: 'first', init: c => c.source[0]}` and `{ name: 'second', init: c => c.source[1]}`.

Answer (score 2):

Postgres supports tuple equality, so you could write this as:

```
DELETE FROM table
WHERE
    _id = $<id>
    AND (item_id, map_id) IN ( 
        ($<item_id>, $<map_id>),
        ($<another_id>, $<another_map_id>),
        ...
    )
```

Comment: ah I was expecting something like that, couldn't find it through all the noise. I'll mark as answer later if no one else answers